# Create a new dataframe counting of all the dates between two dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns 'start_date' and 'end_date' for about 2,000 records. I want to create a new dataframe that counts all of the dates between the start and end date and creates a dataframe that sums these counts for each date as follows:

start and end dataframe

| ID | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |
| 2 | 02/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |
| 3 | 01/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |

date count dataframe

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 |
| 02/01/2021 | 3 |
| 03/01/2021 | 3 |
| 04/01/2021 | 2 |

Answer (score 2):

If medium/large DataFrame for [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984531/2901002) is better avoid `explode` with `date_range`, better is use `repeat` with adding `timedeltas`:

```
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"], dayfirst=True)
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"], dayfirst=True)

#subtract values and convert to days
s = df["end_date"].sub(df["start_date"]).dt.days + 1

#repeat index
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(s)].copy()

#add days by timedeltas
add = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
df1 = (df["start_date"].add(add)
                       .value_counts()
                       .sort_index()
                       .rename_axis('date')
                       .reset_index(name='count'))

print (df1)
        date  count
0 2021-01-01      2
1 2021-01-02      3
2 2021-01-03      3
3 2021-01-04      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.date_range` to get individual dates between `start_date` and `end_date` for each of the rows, then explode it, and finally call `value_counts`

```py
>>> out = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_date'], x['end_date']),
                   axis=1).explode().value_counts()
```

If needed call `to_frame()` passing the column name for counts and reset and rename the index column:

```py
>>> out.to_frame('count').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
        date  count
0 2021-01-03      3
1 2021-01-02      3
2 2021-01-04      2
3 2021-01-01      2
```

Don't forget to convert `start_date` and `end_date` columns to `datetime` type if they are not:

```py
>>> df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
>>> df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# Convert dates in dd/mm/yyyy to datetime format
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], dayfirst=True)

# Create date ranges for each row
date_rng = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start_date'], x['end_date']), axis=1)

# expand dates in range dates into separate rows and count unique dates
df_out = df.assign(date=date_rng).explode('date').groupby('date')['date'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

        date  count
0 2021-01-01      2
1 2021-01-02      3
2 2021-01-03      3
3 2021-01-04      2
```

Comment: @pip   Welcome!  Pleased to help!  :-)